# How to access a method and pass an argument within the template?

Tags: typo3, fluid, extbase, typo3-6.1.x, typo3-6.2.x

In my template I want check whether an entity has a relation to another one. Meaning one object is in an attached Object Storage of another one.

In the controller I can simply call:

```
if ($product->getCategory()->offsetExists($category) {
    print 'In category ' . $category->getName();
}
```

But I can't figure out the correct syntax in the template. I tried those without luck (both evaluate to `true` everytime):

```
<f:if condition="{product.category.offsetExists(category)}">true</f:if>    
<f:if condition="{product.category.offsetExists({category})}">true</f:if>
```

Is this even possible within the template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Additionally to **sretuer's** answer, I'll only mention that you can create VH which will display block conditionally like:

File `typo3conf/ext/your_ext/ViewHelpers/CheckOffsetViewHelper.php`

```
<?php
namespace VENDORNAME\YourExt\ViewHelpers;

class CheckOffsetViewHelper extends \TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\Core\ViewHelper\AbstractViewHelper {
    public function render() {
        return ($product->getCategory()->offsetExists($category)) 
               ? $this->renderChildren()
               : '';
    }
}
?>
```

So you can use it in the view:

```
{namespace vh=VENDORNAME\YourExt\ViewHelpers}

<vh:checkOffset product="{product}" category="{category}" >
    Display this only if product is in category 
</vh:checkOffset>
```

Of course you need to fix `VENDORNAME` and `YourExt` according to your extension, can be found at the beginning of every controller, model, repository etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot again - I totally forgot to come back here and give a thumbs up.

Comment: I do not dare to touch you code. @thomas-hörner did add a comment for you as NAA: *You forgot the brackets for the method renderChildren. It did not run without the brackets in my code.

return ($product->getCategory()->offsetExists($category)) ? $this->renderChildren(): "";*

Comment: @bummi and Thomas thank you for pointing missing brackets, that's StackOverflow feel free to edit other's answers/questions especially if they contains nasty bugs; btw sorry for this ;) I wrote from top of the head

Comment: according to the [book](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseFluidBook/8-Fluid/8-developing-a-custom-viewhelper.html) the class file has to be under `typo3conf/ext/your_ext/Classes/ViewHelpers/CheckOffsetViewHelper.php`, otherwise the autoloader will not find the class by namespace

Answer (score 3):

You can only access properties via Getter from Fluid with no parameters, but you can implement an own ViewHelper to check that. As parameters you can use your Product and the Category. Then you can call your ViewHelper from Fluid this way:

```
<vh:checkOffset product="{product}" category="{category}" />
```

or inline

```
{vh:checkOffset(product: product, category: category)}
```

Within your ViewHelper you can check this in the way you've done it in your Controller:

```
public function render($product, $category){
    return ($product->getCategory()->offsetExists($category));
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot again - I totally forgot to come back here and give a thumbs up.

Answer (score 1):

You may consider https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/vhs/master/Condition/Iterator/ContainsViewHelper.html which is designed for creating conditions in Fluid that check if an array or Iterator contains another object and works exactly like `f:if` regarding `then` and `else` arguments and `f:then` and `f:else` child nodes.