# How do I call an entity method in a TYPO3 fluid template?

Tags: typo3, fluid

I have a template with a line like this:

```
<f:format.htmlentitiesDecode>
    {product.features}
</f:format.htmlentitiesDecode>
```

where "features" is an attribute of the "product" data model.

I would like to print the result if a method call on product instead. Something like:

```
<f:format.htmlentitiesDecode>
    {product.getStrippedFeatures}
</f:format.htmlentitiesDecode>
```

but that gives me empty content.

How can I call a method in the product model and print its output?

Answer (score 6):

Just add the function in your product model like:

```
public function getStrippedFeatures()
{
    return your_stripping_method($this->features);
}
```

Fluid calls attributes with a prefixed `get`, so you only need this in the template:

```
{product.strippedFeatures}
```

Comment: Fluid also looks for the prefixes `is` and `has`.

Comment: The part that fluid calls attributes with a "get" prefix did the trick - **thanks**! I thought about adding a viewhelper but its working now. ViewHelper: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24612883/how-to-access-a-method-and-pass-an-argument-within-the-template)

Comment: Meh I was too late^^

Comment: Early bird and worms. :)

Comment: Could be good to know that the Getter needs to be public in order for this to work

Comment: Also noteworthy: If your method is called `isRoot` or `hasStrippedFeatures` then imho *unintuitively* you have to use `{root}` and `{strippedFeatures}` in fluid (I think `{isRoot}` and `{hasStrippedFeatures}` would have been the far better choice).